# How to fix flutter or dart mismatch version?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

When I ran my flutter project, it gave me this error

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.17.0-105.0.dev.

Because lints 2.0.0 requires SDK version >=2.17.0-206.0.dev <3.0.0 and no versions of lints match >2.0.0 <3.0.0, lints ^2.0.0 is forbidden.

So, because firebase_flutter depends on flutter_lints ^2.0.0 which depends on lints ^2.0.0, version solving failed.

pub get failed (1; So, because firebase_flutter depends on flutter_lints ^2.0.0 which depends on lints ^2.0.0, version solving failed.)
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yasHc.png)

Is there anybody who can help me please?

Comment: download new flutter sdk and replace the old one

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using `beta`, `dev` or `master` Flutter channel instead of `stable`.

Simply run `flutter upgrade` to get the latest Flutter version, which should include a newer Dart beta version as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is 'pub outdated' command.

https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-outdated

You can analyze 'flutter pub outdated' or 'dart pub outdated' command.
And you can update all 'flutter pub upgrade' or 'dart pub upgrade'.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the version Code in front of package its automatically adapt competible version.